# Forest tree bounding box inappropriately expanded by arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am typesetting some trees with arrows. Unfortunately, the arrows change the bounding box more than the space they actually take up.

I would like to figure out a way to set the tree's bounding box either to the actual size of the picture, or even just to keep the bounding box unaffected by the arrows.

`forest` does include the option of creating a node that is fit to the tree, and it has the option `use as bounding box`, but the latter can only be used in tree nodes, and not nodes created in a different way.

Is there a way to achieve this in a general way, i.e. without having to change the spacing manually? I am typesetting many of these kinds of trees and I would prefer to not have to do this for each of them separately.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    
    awawa
    \begin{forest}
        [a[b, name=b][1[2[3[c, name=c]]]]]
        {\draw[->] (b) to[out=west, in=south] (c);}
    \end{forest}
    
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: tree's bounding box expanded too much to the left and downwards]

*The bounding box of this tree is expanded too much to the left and downwards, I assume this is because of the control points of the arrows.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the bounding box is so large is because it includes the control points of the curved path:

[image]

To set the bounding box without the additional arrow, use the command `\pgfresetboundingbox` after the tree. Then use `\useasboundingbox` to set the bounding box to a rectangle that contains all the tree nodes. That node can be created using the code

```
\node(BB)[use as bounding box, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, fit to=tree]{};
```

after the code for the forest nodes. The issue is then that the arrow may overlap the surrounding text:

[image]

So you'll need to add a bit of vertical space. This is all coded into a macro `\myboundingbox` that takes an optional argument to add vertical space below the tree.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\myboundingbox}[1][0]{
    \node(BB)[use as bounding box, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, fit to=tree]{};
    \pgfresetboundingbox\useasboundingbox(BB.north west)rectangle([yshift=-#1]BB.south east);
}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    
    awawa
    \begin{forest}
        [a[b, name=b][1[2[3[c, name=c]]]]]
        \draw[->] (b) to[out=west, in=south] (c);
        \myboundingbox[3ex]      
    \end{forest}
    
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to find the control points of the drawn arrows easily? i'm sure with a bit (with a sufficient definition of "a bit") of math it would be possible to find the bounding boxes of the bézier curves and set the bounding box of the picture appropriately.

Comment: @matea: With `show path construction` (using `decorations.pathreplacing`) the control points are `(\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)` and `(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)`, which is how I drew the first figure. But I'm not sure what you mean by "appropriately". It sounds like you want to ignore those, unless I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: basically i was thinking that every time an arrow is added one could compute the resulting curve's bounding box (like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809978/calculating-the-bounding-box-of-cubic-bezier-curve) and update the bonding box of the picture to include this. i tried to implement this myself but i don't think i have the necessary tikz skills so i think i will just stick to manual bounding box adjustments for now.